# Incorrect redirect_uri after payment success

Tags: wepay

```
{
    "account_id": 1095208329,
    "short_description": "Freelance services rendered",
    "type": "service",
    "amount": 1.67,
    "currency": "USD",
    "hosted_checkout": {
        "mode": "iframe",
        "redirect_uri": "https://kumarpatel.github.io/admin-portal/#/invoice/268"
    }
}
```

After the above payment is completed in the the embedded iframe, I am redirected to `https://kumarpatel.github.io/admin-portal/?checkout_id=599080470#/invoice/268`

instead of `https://kumarpatel.github.io/admin-portal/#/invoice/268`

Comment: It's not incorrect, it's just adding the transaction ID to the query string for your reference. You could store it and use the ID later to look up the transaction via https://developer.wepay.com/api/api-calls/checkout.

Comment: transaction ID (checkout_id) has been appended in the wrong part of my redirect_uri. It should be appended at the end of my uri.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because it's a query string parameter, which means it can't go after the `#`.